# JWT security in OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect, auth0

I have decided to jump on the bandwaggon and start using OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect for the authentication and authorization of my next project, but I'm struggling to understand how a JWT can be secure.

I am using Angular 8 for the front end with a node.js backend and Auth0 as my the identity service provider (the wrong terminology, I know. Forgotten it.)

I have watched two or three PluralSight courses on these subjects but none really go over using the JWT on a node.js back end, mostly they concentrate on the .NET stack which takes a lot of the labour out of it I guess.

My problem is this: how can I be sure that the JWT token sent to my API is one that comes from Auth0? I understand that the token has a signature, and I imagine Auth0 have some private secret they use to sign the JWT, but what is to prevent some malevolent entity creating a JWT with exactly the same content and signing with a different secret and sending that to my API? In the .NET samples I've seen, I see no mention of checking that the signature's secret corresponds to Auth0's. What checks are necessary on the API — .NET, node.js or otherwise — to ensure the JWT is authentic?

And how would this work with nodejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly or what, but JWT is signed and verified by the same secret (if HMAC algo is used), so the answer to your first question would be:

- **if it's tampered, you will be notified during validation, because signing with a different secret is what gives it away, that the token has been compromised.**

Not sure what libraries are you using, but for Node.js, the [jsonwebtoken package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) has a *jwt.verify(token, secret)* function, that takes in your token and secret values as arguments. This is basically all you need and can have for verification.

Comment: That sounds around the right area, and thank you for putting up with my terminology issues. I guess from what you've said, I need to know the secret with which the JWT was signed? Is this public? With OAuth 2.0  and OpenID Connect implemented by Auth0, for example, will I have access to this secret?

Comment: Ok, after a little look on the Auth0 site, it transpires that I do have access to the secret, so I am reasonably satisfied that the JWT is secure! Thanks @Lukas

Comment: Also, I'm not sure about your settings, but if possible, try storing tokens in HTTP cookies, to prevent from XSS attacks. Here's a link for more details [Where to Store your JWTs](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage) @serlingpa